# summing nodes' values grouping by pattern of other nodes' values

Tags: regex, xslt, grouping

#### The set-up

I have an XML file with (this is simplified from actual):

```
<feeds xmlns...>
  <feed>
    <week>
      <start-date>...</start-date>
      <end-date>...</end-date>
      <entry>
        <data name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <data name="path" value="/news/releases/2011-12-05/xyzzy"/>
        <numeric name="bar" value="463284">
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <data name="foo" value="baz"/>
        <data name="path" value="/pages/ISOcodes/en-US"/>
        <numeric name="bar" value="4332">
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <data name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <data name="path" value="/"/>
        <numeric name="bar" value="23232">
      </entry>
    </week>
    ...
  </feed>
  ...
</feeds>
```

Each `week` has many `entry`s; each `entry` has just two `data` elements, one with `name="foo"` and the other with `name="path"`, and a single `numeric` element with `name="bar"` and `value` an integer. There can be partial-duplicate `entry`s, even within a `week`: `entry`s can have the same `foo` or the same `path`, but no two `entry`s within a week that have the same `foo` *and* the same `path`.

#### What I want

I'd like to separate my `path`s into categories. For example, I want all `path`s matching the regex `/ISOcodes/` to be considered separately (as "ISOcodes", say) and all `paths` matching `^/news` as a separate category ("news").

I'm trying to sum the `value` of `bar` across multiple `entry`s within a single `week`, grouping by `foo` and by *type* (as in previous paragraph) of `path`. That is, for each `week`, for each `value` of `foo`, for each category of `path` (as in the preceding paragraph), I want the `sum()` of the `value`s of `bar`.

**Is there a way to do this? How?**

Comment: Is XSLT 2.0 available to you?

Comment: @LarsH: Yes. Feel free to retag [tag:xslt-2.0] if appropriate, of course.

Answer (score 3):

An XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="week">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" 
                            group-by="concat(data[@name='foo']/@value, '-', 
                    if (matches(data[@name='path']/@value, '/ISOcodes/')) 
                        then 'ISOcodes' 
                    else if (matches(data[@name='path']/@value, '^/news')) 
                        then 'news' 
                    else 'no_category')">
            [<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>]
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/numeric/@value)"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the following input:

```
<feeds>
    <feed>
        <week>
            <start-date>...</start-date>
            <end-date>...</end-date>
            <entry>
                <data name="foo" value="bar"/>
                <data name="path" value="/news/releases/2011-12-05/xyzzy"/>
                <numeric name="bar" value="463284"/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <data name="foo" value="baz"/>
                <data name="path" value="/pages/ISOcodes/test"/>
                <numeric name="bar" value="4332"/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <data name="foo" value="baz"/>
                <data name="path" value="/pages/ISOcodes/en-US"/>
                <numeric name="bar" value="4332"/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <data name="foo" value="baz"/>
                <data name="path" value="/pages/ISOcodes/japan"/>
                <numeric name="bar" value="4332"/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <data name="foo" value="bar"/>
                <data name="path" value="/"/>
                <numeric name="bar" value="23232"/>
            </entry>
        </week>
    </feed>
</feeds>
```

Produces:

```
[bar-news]
463284
[baz-ISOcodes]
12996
[bar-no_category]
23232
```

Obviously, you'll need to format additional elements to taste, but this should demonstrate the grouping method.

Comment: +1. Thank you! This looks like what I want. Going to read up on `xsl:for-each-group`, `current-grouping-key()`, and `current-group()`....

Comment: Wow, that's quite a group-by. :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

**XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//week">
  <xsl:for-each-group  select="entry" group-by="./data[@name = 'foo']/@value">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="data[@name = 'path']/@value">
      <xsl:message>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-group()/data[@name = 'path' and matches(@value, '/ISOcodes/')]">
            Sum of ISO codes : <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/numeric/@value)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="current-group()/data[@name = 'path' and matches(@value, '^/news')]">
            Sum of news : <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/numeric/@value)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            Sum of other categories : <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/numeric/@value)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

When applied to this .xml file :

```
<feeds>
  <feed>
    <week>
      <start-date>...</start-date>
      <end-date>...</end-date>
      <entry>
        <data name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <data name="path" value="/news/releases/2011-12-05/xyzzy"/>
        <numeric name="bar" value="463284"/>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <data name="foo" value="baz"/>
        <data name="path" value="/pages/ISOcodes/en-US"/>
        <numeric name="bar" value="4332"/>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <data name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <data name="path" value="/"/>
        <numeric name="bar" value="23232"/>
      </entry>
    </week>
    ...
  </feed>
  ...
</feeds>
```

**The output is:**

```
[xslt]                 Sum of news : 463284
[xslt]
[xslt]                 Sum of other categories : 23232
[xslt]
[xslt]                 Sum of ISO codes : 4332
```

**Edit:**

I thought you wanted the sum? So my code printed the sum :)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//week">
      <xsl:for-each-group  select="entry" group-by="./data[@name = 'foo']/@value">
        <xsl:variable name="foo" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="data[@name = 'path']/@value">
          <xsl:message>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()/data[@name = 'path' and matches(@value, '/ISOcodes/')]">
                Sum of <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>-<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/> : <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/numeric/@value)"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()/data[@name = 'path' and matches(@value, '^/news')]">
                Sum of <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>-<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/> : <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/numeric/@value)"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                Sum of other categories : <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/numeric/@value)"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:message>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

This prints all the bells and whistles too :)

Comment: The output I seek is grouped by `foo` *and* by the `path` pattern (simultaneously). I don't (yet) understand your XSL, but if the output you posted is correct then your XSL doesn't do what I'm looking for.

Comment: @msh210 I have no idea what you are talking about. I posted a well-formed .xml with duplicate entries, specifically to point out that it works. I now changed my answer to use your .xml.

Comment: What I mean is that (assuming the output you posted is correct) you're grouping by `<data name="path">`s only, and not by `<data name="foo">`s. I sought both. Thanks, though, for trying; perhaps my question insufficiently clear.

Comment: @msh210 The code is clear. Does it matter that I do a two step grouping for clarity? I could write everything in one line if you wanted :)

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yes, the code is clear: what it prints is incorrect (it doesn't print `data[@name='foo']/@value`). +1.